# How to use type_traits to generate code dependent on if a class specialisation exists?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to write a `class template Hasher` which will be implemented in two different ways depending on whether or not `std::hash<T>` has been implemented for T:

```
template<typename T>
struct Hasher
{
  std::size_t hash( T t ) const;
  // implement as A { std::hash<T> h; return h( t ); }
  //           or B { std::hash<std::string> h; return h( t.to_string() );  }
};
```

If `std::hash<T>` has been specialised, I want to use it.  If not, I expect `T` to have a `to_string()` function to return a key for me to hash on.

For example, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), if `T` is `long long`, a pointer, or `std::string`, I want version A.  If it is not one of those standard ones listed and if the user has not specialised `std::hash<T>` for his own type, I expect `T` to have a `std::string to_string() const` for me to call.  In this case, I want to generate version B.

**PROBLEM**

How do I use C++11/type_traits/no-SFINAE to generate the proper implementation?

**ADDENDUM**

Another way to think about it:

It's almost like I want version B to be the default behavior (ie, if no specialization exists, to use version B).

**TESTED NAWAZ'S SOLUTION**

I just tried out Nawaz's solution on gcc 4.8.1 as his came in first and is actually the easiest for me to read and understand (more important).

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
class Hasher
{
        // overloading rules will select this one first...  ...unless it's not valid
        template<typename U>
        static auto hash_impl(U const& u, int)
                -> decltype(std::hash<U>().operator()( u ))
        {
                 return std::hash<U>().operator()( u );
        }
        // as a fallback, we will pick this one
        template<typename U>
        static auto hash_impl(U const& u, ... )
                -> std::size_t
        {
                 return std::hash<std::string>().operator()(u.to_string());
        }

public:
        auto hash( T t ) const -> decltype( hash_impl(t,0) )
        {
                 return hash_impl( t, 0 );
        }
};

struct Foo
{
        std::string  m_id;
        std::string  to_string() const { return m_id; }
};

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        std::string        s{ "Bar" };
        Foo                f{ s     };
        long long          l{ 42ll  };

        Hasher<long long>   hl;
        Hasher<Foo>         hf;
        Hasher<std::string> hs;

        assert( hl.hash( l )==l );
        assert( hf.hash( f )==hs.hash( s ));

        return 0;
}
```

**TESTED DANIEL FREY'S SOLUTION**

Daniel's implementation is also very interesting.  By computing first whether or not we have a hash, I am able to use tag-dispatch to select the implementation I want.  We have a nice pattern/separation-of-concerns which leads to very clean code.

However, in the implementation of `has_hash<>`, the arguments to `decltype` confused me at first.  In fact, it shouldn't read as arguments.  Rather, it is a list of expressions (comma separated expressions).  We need to follow the rules as expressed [here](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/c-c/57830-c-tip-what-comma-separated-expressions.html).

> C++ ensures that each of the expressions is evaluated and its side
>   effects take place. However, the value of an entire comma-separated
>   expression is only the result of the rightmost expression.

Also, the use of `void()` was a mystery to me at first.  When I changed it to `double()` to see what would happen, it was clear why it really should be `void()` (so we don't need to pass in that second template parameter).

```
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

template< typename, typename = void >
struct has_hash
  : std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct has_hash< T, decltype( std::hash< T >()( std::declval< T >() ), void() ) >
  : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
class Hasher
{
        static std::size_t hash_impl(T const& t, std::true_type::type )
        {
                 return std::hash<T>().operator()( t );
        }

        static std::size_t hash_impl(T const& t, std::false_type::type )
        {
                 return std::hash<std::string>().operator()(t.to_string());
        }

public:
        std::size_t hash( T t ) const
        {
                 return hash_impl( t, typename has_hash<T>::type() );
        }
};

struct Foo
{
        std::string  m_id;
        std::string  to_string() const { return m_id; }
};

int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        std::string        s{ "Bar" };
        Foo                f{ s     };
        long long          l{ 42ll  };

        Hasher<long long>   hl;
        Hasher<Foo>         hf;
        Hasher<std::string> hs;

        assert( hl.hash( l )==l );
        assert( hf.hash( f )==hs.hash( s ));

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use **Expression SFINAE** introduced by C++11.

Here is one example how it is implemented:

```
template<typename T>
struct Hasher
{
    auto hash( T t ) const -> decltype(hash_impl(t,0))
    {
       return hash_impl(t, 0);
    }
  private:
    template<typename U>
    static auto hash_impl(U const & u, int) -> decltype(std::hash<U>().hash(u))
    {
       return std::hash<U>().hash(u);
    }
    template<typename U>
    static auto hash_impl(U const & u, ... ) -> std::string
    {
       return u.to_string();
    }
};
```

Note that `hash_impl` is an overloaded function template. So when you write this:

```
       return hash_impl(t, 0);
```

Since the second argument `0` is `int`, the above **first** *attempts* to invoke `hash_impl` which uses `std::hash` — this attempt might fail if `std::hash<U>().hash(u)` is not a valid expression (**Expression SFINAE**). If that fails, then the second `hash_impl` is invoked.

Comment: wrong order?  OP wanys `hash` if it exists, and only if it fails `to_string`?

Comment: @Yakk: Ohh, yes. Fixed. :-)

Comment: I'd be tempted to stick in _another_ `std::hash<T>().hash(u)` as a second fallback, so if neither exist the compiler error tells you to specialize `hash` rather than adding a `to_string` member.

Comment: @MooingDuck make the `to_string` take a `double` (or a `sink`), and the second `std::hash<T>().hash(u)` take `...`?  ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could just test if `std::hash<T>()(...)` can be called with type in question. If so, you'll get back a type from `decltype()` which can be used in a SFINAE expression to determine the size of a return type:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_hash
{
    template <typename S>
    static char (&test(S*, decltype(std::hash<S>()(std::declval<T&>()))* = 0))[1];
    static char (&test(...))[2];
    static constexpr bool value = 1 == sizeof(test(static_cast<T*>(0)));
};
```

Base on this you could then use the `has_hash<T>::value` to determine if there is a usable hash function already defined.

Comment: I'd probably stick that in a macro for readability's sake, if not reuse.

Comment: @MooingDuck: come on! This code isn't that hard to read... OK, few people regularly declare functions return references to arrays and `std::declval<T>()` is probably also rare in normal code. It would be cool if something like this would be a language built-in in some form. On the other hand, there are many odd things which can be test already and if there will be a language built-in is an interesting question...

Comment: You can have the overloads return std::true_type and std::false_type and that makes everything better. Like garlic.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to test if an expression is valid or not, I prefer the following implementation:

```
template< typename, typename = void >
struct has_hash
  : std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct has_hash< T, decltype( std::hash< T >()( std::declval< T >() ), void() ) >
//                            ^^ expression here ------------------^^
  : std::true_type {};
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87346d617d3bf26e)

Comment: +1 I like the conciseness of this implementation, but can you explain to me what is happening inside that decltype()?  Does it just keep evaluating expressions from left-to-right until it finds one that works?

Comment: @kfmfe04: `decltype` returns the type of the expression, here *coma operator* is used: The first expression(s) is for SFINAE, the last expression is for the result type (`void`). If any expression is invalid, the template specialization is discarded.

Comment: @Jarod42 ty - I found a good explanation of comma-delimited expressions here: http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/c-c/57830-c-tip-what-comma-separated-expressions.html  I've used them before, but didn't realise that the entire expression has the value of the last sub-expression.  Also, I played around with Daniel Frey's Live example to understand why we need a void() there, instead of a double() or something else.  When I find some time, I will try to write a version using this implementation and add it to the OP.

Comment: @kfmfe04: expression should return `void` here, as according to generic version `has_hash<T>` is in fact `has_hash<T, void>` with the default template value. So we have to specialize `has_hash<T, void>`.

Comment: @kfmfe04 Jarod already provided some good explanation, so I'd just like to add that the technique is both very scalable and has a good signal-to-noise ratio once you understand how it work. Just keep it in your bag-o-tricks in case you need it :)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another implementation

First, some boilerplate.  `type_sink` and `TypeSink` let us evaluate types, and discard them.

```
template<typename... T> struct type_sink {typedef void type;};
template<typename... T> using TypeSink = typename type_sink<T>::type;
```

We then write a really simple `has_hash` that uses SFINAE.  The default choice is "no hash", and the specialization is valid iff `std::hash<T>()( t )` is a valid expression for a variable `t` of type `T`:

```
template<typename T, typename=void> struct has_hash:std::false_type {};
template<typename T> struct has_hash<
  T, TypeSink< decltype( std::hash<T>()( std::declval<T&>() ) ) >
>: std::true_type {};
```

we then write our universal hasher:

```
template<typename T>
struct Hasher
{
private:
  typedef has_hash< typename std::decay<T>::type > test_for_hash;
public:
  std::size_t operator()( T t ) const {
    return hash( std::forward<T>(t), test_for_hash() );
  }
private:
  std::size_t hash( T t, std::true_type has_hash ) const {
    return std::hash<T>()( std::forward<T>(t) );
  }
  std::size_t hash( T t, std::false_type no_hash ) const {
    // TODO: static_assert that t.to_string exists, and if not give a useful error message
    return std::hash<std::string>()( std::forward<T>(t).to_string() )
  }
};
```

where we use the `has_hash` trait to do tagged dispatching to either the "use `hash` directly" or "`to_string` then `hash`".

We can do more layers of this dispatching.

I took the liberty of making it somewhat move-aware, in that `T` can be `T&` or `T const&` or `T` and it behaves reasonably.  (I don't know about `T&&` off the top of my head).

As noted in other comments, some work to generate better error messages can be done.  We want the compiler's error message to complain about the lack of a `hash<T>` implementation rather than a `to_string` implementation probably.  That would involve writing a `has_to_string` traits class and either doing another layer of tag dispatching, or doing a `static_assert` to generate a useful message telling the end user to implement either the `hash<T>` specialization or `T::to_string`.

Another option would be to make a universal hasher:

```
template<typename T>
struct Hasher
{
private:
  typedef has_hash< T > test_for_hash;
public:
  template<typename U>
  std::size_t operator()( U&& u ) const {
    return hash( std::forward<U>(u), test_for_hash() );
  }
private:
  template<typename U>
  std::size_t hash( U&& u, std::true_type has_hash ) const {
    return std::hash<T>()( std::forward<U>(u) ); // conversion occurs here
  }
  template<typename U>
  std::size_t hash( U&& u, std::false_type no_hash ) const {
    // TODO: static_assert that t.to_string exists, and if not give a useful error message
    T t = std::forward<U>(u); // conversion occurs here -- note, implicit on purpose!
    return std::hash<std::string>()( std::move(t).to_string() )
  }
};
```

which defers transformation-to-`T` until the last moment.